# Is this use of reinterpret_cast undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm not sure about this piece of code:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "HI!\n"; }

struct fobj
{
    void operator()() const { std::cout << "Bye!\n"; }
};

using slot_t = std::function<void()>;
std::list<slot_t> slot_list;

template<class F>
inline std::size_t insert_slot(F f)
{
    auto it = slot_list.insert(slot_list.begin(), f);
    return reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(&*it);
}

inline slot_t& recover_slot(std::size_t conn_id)
{ return *reinterpret_cast<slot_t*>(conn_id); }

int main()
{
   std::size_t conn1_id = insert_slot(f);
   std::size_t conn2_id = insert_slot(fobj());

   recover_slot(conn1_id)(); // HI!
   recover_slot(conn2_id)(); // Bye!
}
```

I don't see the `reinterpret_cast<T*>(some_size_t)` any different from `static_cast<T*>(some_void_ptr)`, but I'm not really sure how risky the former is.

Comment: It might be slightly less UB if you use `uintptr_t` instead of `size_t`.

Comment: @PaulSanders Isn't `std::size_t` guaranteed to be as big as any memory address?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, but `uintptr_t` exists for a reason.

Comment: UB or not...it's terrifying.

Comment: "The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object". Usually it is big enough to hold an address, but there have been architectures or environmental limitations where this does not hold. You could add a `static_assert` to verify that `sizeof(size_t) >= sizeof(&f)`. `uintptr_t` is big enough to hold an address, but is an optional type that may not be provided. It would be safer to use it rather than `size_t`.

Comment: It is explicitly allowed to `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to a sufficiently large integral type and back; the result is guaranteed to be equal to the original pointer. So, assuming `size_t` happens to be large enough, or you switch to `uintptr_t`, your example is well-defined. That said, it's unclear why you want to round-trip through an integer. Why not pass around `slot_t*`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Because originally there was no swing.